# How do I exclude a column from pandas pd.get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 82 columns, and would like to turn all column values into dummy variables using pd.get_dummies ***except*** for the first column "business_id".

How can I define the pd.get_dummies function to only work on the other 81 columns?

Comment: Use `columns=df.columns[1:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude columns based on location by slicing `df.columns`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
                   'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3],
                   'D': [4, 5, 6]})

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns[1:])

# For Display
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
A  B_a  B_b  B_c  C_1  C_2  C_3  D_4  D_5  D_6
a    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
b    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
a    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

---

For a more general solution, you can filter out particular columns programmatically using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) over your `df.columns`.

Put whatever column names you want to exclude in `columns_to_exclude`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
                   'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3],
                   'D': [4, 5, 6]})

columns_to_exclude = ['B', 'D']
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=filter(
    lambda i: i not in columns_to_exclude,
    df.columns))

# For Display
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
A B  C  D  A_a  A_b  C_1  C_2  C_3
a b  1  4    1    0    1    0    0
b a  2  5    0    1    0    1    0
a c  3  6    1    0    0    0    1
```